# Is it grammatically correct to add "anyway" at the end of this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs

This is a sentence from a short story I'm writing:

> "It's all the same to me, because when it comes to our deepest fears
>   and insecurities, we are all alone."

I'm not very sure if this is more grammatically correct:

> "It's all the same to me, because when it comes to our deepest fears
>   and insecurities, we are all alone anyway."

**EDIT:**

I'm not sure if this is necessary, but here I include the two lines preceding the sentence.

> "Do you think there is something on the other side of the fog?"
>
> "I'm not
>   sure. Do you wish there were something else?"

Comment: For a start, "Anyways" is wrong. It should be "Anyway" (without the "s") http://grammartips.homestead.com/anyway.html

Comment: Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Why do you think it *anyway* is necessary? If you're looking for writing critique you can try [writers.se].

Comment: @Matt Эллен Sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: What's wrong with 'anyways'? The OP's example seems to be a piece of dialogue, and the use of 'anyways' may be consistent with the character who says it.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's grammatical. Whether you use it or not depends on the effect you're trying to create.

Answer (score 5):

It adds a sense of resignation to the sentence. Either is acceptable, but they convey different moods or senses. The first has a feeling of hopelessness, whereas the second has a resigned hopelessness. It all depends what is meant.